# Change a list item with jquery if the user is signed in using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a list item in the navigation bar with text: "Sign in". On my codeignter controller I have a function that returns the username of the user that is signed in. How can I use AJAX to change the name of the list item to the php variable returned by my CI controller?

Answer (score 3):

you would need to setup a controller to handle this, and then call the url via ajax and on `success()` alter the DOM element

### Controller

```
<?php
function getusername(){
  //dosomething
  echo json_encode($username);
}
```

### ajax

```
$.ajax({
  //url to the above controller
  url: "/auth/getusername",
  dataType: "JSON",
  //on success, get the echo'd data json data from the controller
  success: function(d){
    //put the json_data into the field via .html()
    $('.username-field').html(d);
  }
});
```

---

My question is, why are you using ajax to do this when you can simply use a conditional statement in your view and on page reload it shows their name? You already are making an HTTP request when logging the user in. Why would you want to make an additional request just to retrieve their username?

#### Pass the $username to the view

```
$data['username'] = 'JohnDoe';
$this->load->view('index/index', $data);
```

#### Using terniary operator form in PHP

```
<?php echo ( isset($username) ) ? $username : 'Guest'; ?>
```

#### Using full length conditional in PHP

```
<?php if( isset($username) ){ echo $username; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
$.get('/index.php/controller/method', function(data) {
  $('#signInBtn').html(data);
});
```

Where the "/index.php/controller/method" would be replaced by your respective controller and method names.

I put a complete example with the HTML associated on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ifigih/edit